# python record separtor file iteration

Tags: python

I have a very very large text file (much larger than can fit in memory).   What I would like to do is use something similar to:

```
for record in myFile:
 process_record();
```

with the added trick that my **records are separated by blank lines** (with all kinds of stuff in between).   For example...

```
data1 
data2,data3,moredata

anotherrecord,otherstuff
yippee
kaiyay
mom

aThird,record:here
```

How would one iterate through the file in python where each loop iteration accesses a single record from the file?

Comment: Do you want the record that's getting processed as a string with newlines or an array of lines?

Comment: @ohaal Either one is fine.   If I get the string I can parse to lines or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a generator function:

```
def records(textfile):
    record_lines = []
    for line in textfile:
        if line != '\n':
            record_lines.append(line)
        else:
            yield ''.join(record_lines)
            record_lines = []
    yield ''.join(record_lines)


for record in records(the_file):
    process(record)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an iterator that joins the lines until you find a blank line.

```
class MyIter:
 def __init__(self, infile):
    self.infile=infile

 def __iter__(self):
    return self

 def next(self):
    lines = []
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    if len(lines)==0:
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        return ",".join(lines)
```

and try it with

```
for line in MyIter(infile):
    print line
```